# Как задать стиль всем элементом с одним id?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Предположим, есть страница, но ширина на javascript задаётся только первому. Как сделать, чтоб стиль задавался сразу всем элементом с каким-то Id?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Div() {
                var W = window.innerWidth - 200;
                var H = window.innerHeight - 50;

                var WMess = window.innerWidth - 280;
                document.getElementById('mess').style.width = WMess + "px";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="Div()">
        <div>
            <div id='mess'>Далинин Станислав</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id='mess'>Далинин Станислав</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Kirpich643 Удаляйте из вопроса лишний код, иначе вероятность получить ответ будет падать.

Comment: вы понимаете на сколько глупо звучит "всем элементам с одним id"? id **должен** быть уникальным на странице!

Comment: Ну предложите свой вариант!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде как нигде не накосячил:

```
<body onLoad="Div()">
    <div>
        <div class='mess'>Далинин Станислав</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='mess'>Далинин Станислав</div>
    </div>
</body>

     function Div() {
         var W = window.innerWidth - 200,
                 H = window.innerHeight - 50,
                 WMess = window.innerWidth - 280;
                 divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

         for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
             if((new RegExp('mess').test(divs[i].className))) {
                 divs[i].style.width = WMess + "px";
             }    
         }
     }
```

Comment: Если не считать велосипеда там где обычные люди используют getElementsByClassName, то да, не накосячил :)

Comment: @Next_Alex велосипед, не велосипед, а вы видать про кроссбраузерность ни ухом ни слухом?

Comment: Если считать IE браузером, то да.
Хотя с 9-й версии он тоже наконец приблизился к стандартам и даже начал поддерживать getElementsByTagName.

Comment: Если чо, getElementsByTagName IE с 6-ой версии поддерживает. С подключением :-). А те, кто не считает IE браузером, теряют большую часть пользователей.

Comment: изобретать велосипед изза MS тоже не айс. пользуйтесь `jquery` =)

Comment: @thunder подключать целую библиотеку для перебора элементов лишь с одним классом для меня как-то сильно :D

Comment: ну почемуто мне кажется, что там много кода js будет ;)

Comment: Согласен, но пример был на чистом JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Подразумевается что id - уникальный для этой страницы идентификатор элемента.
Если нужно создать несколько однотипных элементов, то используется атрибут class.

Answer (score 0):

используйте `class` и `jquery`

а так читайте про функцию `foreach` и обходите поочереди ВСЕ элементы с `id=mess`

id -- ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР и он ДОЛЖЕН быть уникальным.